# Highchart: Spline with clickable Symbols

Tags: highcharts

i like to show additional informations on a highchart graph by clicking on a datapoint. I like to visualise this "clickpoint" by setting a flag. That can be done linke the sun that will be shown here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/gray

But i did not find any information in the api how to make this marker clickable. Isnt it possible? In the highstocks API i found clickable flags that can be set. But i need to use the highcharts api only.

Maybe some of you have solved this problem and an give me some hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can catch it by [click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) function on the point.